# Self join in criteria query

Tags: java, jpa, orm, criteria-api, self-join

so I have a table called 'User' having fields as

- userId
- userName
- supervisorId

I want to fetch the userName of the supervisor of a particular user.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(User.class);
Root<User> rootUser = criteriaQuery.from(User.class);
List<Predicate> predList = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
Join<User, User> selfJoin = rootUser.join("userId", JoinType.LEFT); //not sure about this line
predList.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(selfJoin.<String>get("userId"), supervisorId)); //supervisorId is the id of the supervisor that I want to find
TypedQuery<User> typedQuery = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<User> resultList = typedQuery.getResultList();
```

Now I have many other conditions too beside this supervisorId. So I have to use the same criteria query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Criteria API is for when you need to [build queries dynamically](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-criteria-api-bulk-update-delete/), and you should always remember that it's based on traversing entities.

What you need there is a plain SQL query like this:

```
select sp.userName
from users u
join users sp on sp.userId = u.supervisorId
where userId = ?
```

Just because you use JPA and Hibernate, [it does not mean that you should not use SQL queries](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-jpa-entitymanager-createnativequery-is-a-magic-wand/).

The Criteria API query can be written fairly easy if you [map the supervisor as a `@ManyToOne` association](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/):

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="supervisorId", referencedColumnName="userId")
private User supervisor;
```

Then, the join becomes:

```
Join<User, User> selfJoin = rootUser.join("supervisor", JoinType.LEFT);
```

Answer (score 3):

An example that I implemented and working for me. This is not an exact code but this one should work. I have not created a reference variable in the same entity.

### *SQL*

```
select right.* from MyTable left, MyTable right where left.subjectid = 7 and left.studentid = right.studentid
and left.subjectid != right.subjectid;
```

### Criteria Code

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<MyTable]> criteria = builder.createQuery(MyTable.class);
Root<MyTable> MyTableRootLeft = criteria.from(MyTable.class);
Root<MyTable> MyTableRootRight = criteria.from(MyTable.class);
Predicate selfJoinPredicate = 
builder.and(
            builder.equal(MyTableRootLeft.get(subjectid), subjectid),
            builder.equal(MyTableRootLeft.get(studentid),MyTableRootRight.get(studentid)),
              builder.notEqual(MyTableRootLeft.get(subjectid),
MyTableRootRight.get(subjectid)));
```