# Fetch children and parents self-referencing with primitive criteria api

Tags: sql, criteria-api

I have an Entity that is self-referencing like so:

```
  @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")
  private Long ParentId;
```

When I do this:

```
Join<Entity, Entity> entityJoin =
    root.join(ParentId, JoinType.LEFT);
```

I get an error:

```
org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Attribute [path.jpa.Entity#ParentId(BASIC)] is not joinable
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is this:

```
select
    *
    from
        entity o1_0 
    where
        exists(select
            1 
        from
            entity o5_0 
        where
            o5_0.PARENT_ID=o1_0.id)
```

I want to fetch the rows that have the PARENT_ID and also the parents. How could I acheive this?

Comment: I do not know Criteria, but the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49253628/self-join-in-criteria-query) suggests that you may need to define the relationship using something like `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` and `@JoinColumn(name="ParentId", referencedColumnName="id")`. If that is not it, I suggest you search for articles using keywords "criteria self join".

Comment: Does this work with with a primitive (Long) or only with Objects?

Comment: It seems these annotations such as OneToOne ManyToOne etc.. only work with Entities and not with basic types such as Long and String.